# Microsoft Access Box & Whisker Graph

Tags: ms-access, statistics, histogram

Is there anyway in Access to create a Box & Whisker Graph? Or an piece of add on code that will do so?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution could be to use PowerBI?  You can download and use for free see - [PowerBi website](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/).  If you pulled the data into a PowerBI desktop file and imported a [custom visual](https://app.powerbi.com/visuals/).  This will allow you to plot the data using a box and Whisker graph for free.  Also using PowerBI for data exploration has many advantages most of which are free.